# Need root to execute shell command "input keyevent <#>" through an app at runtime?

Tags: android, linux, shell

I'm trying to execute the adb shell command `input keyevent 5` to answer a call through my app at run time.

If I do this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent 5");
```

It doesn't seem to execute (nothing is happening). But when I do this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "input keyevent 5"});
```

The expected simulated tap on the answer button on-screen happens. Which is good.

However one problem is that on some devices which are rooted using Superuser, the command takes a while to get the superuser permission. It works fine with devices which have Chainfire's SuperSU su binary.

My question is:
Is it possible to execute this command without root through Java code at runtime?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that would be a bit scary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely no!

That would an absolute major security issue, ergo you have to be rooted.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I never replied to this. Anyway, the app I was making was intended to be a QA tool used internally by my company (they deal with RF stuff). I agree with your answer entirely :)

Comment: @Elliptica it should work. What error are you getting? Are you sure your rooted device has `su`? Also ensure the root management app is configured to allow your app to call `su`

Comment: It looks like I definitely have to use this style command `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "input keyevent 5"});` but that on some phones that's not sufficient, and I also have to put it in system/apps and give it chmod 777 permissions before it works.