# Android - Delay When Answering Calls Programmatically on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, phone-call, android-5.1.1-lollipop, incoming-call

I'm working on an app that can answer phone calls programmatically. Iv'e read much about it, and tried many methods to get it to work.

The only true solution that works for me in versions 5.0 and up is as followed -

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " + Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
```

Although this method works, the actual answering time is delayed by 1.5 to 5 seconds. This delay is a real deal breaker, since my app needs to intercept all incoming calls, and I can't have it delaying the answering process.

Is there any other method that works faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to another answer[1] this depends on the Super user client used. `Chainfire's SuperSU`[2] is said to be faster than `Superuser`

[1] [Need root to execute shell command "input keyevent <#>" through an app at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282553/need-root-to-execute-shell-command-input-keyevent-through-an-app-at-runtim)

[2] https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, if only the root method works for you, one way is to keep the root shell open with your background service, and pipe the input keyevent command to it when needed.  This would save the startup time of the process and the shell every time the call comes in.  You can do this easily with libraries such as [RootShell](https://github.com/Stericson/RootShell/wiki/Usage).